# Scraping html text into table with delimiters that do not have a clear pattern using R (rvest)

Tags: html, r, dataframe, web-scraping, rvest

I'm just learning how to use R to scrape data from webpages, and I'm running into a couple of issues.

For reference, the website that I am practicing on is here: http://www.rsssf.com/tables/34q.html

As far as I know, the website I am scraping data from is not a table so I can't directly scrape the information into a table, so here is the code I wrote to just have all of the text:

```
wcq_1934_html <- read_html("http://www.rsssf.com/tables/34q.html")
wcq_1934_node <- html_nodes(wcq_1934_html, "pre")
wcq_1934_text <- html_text(wcq_1934_node, trim = TRUE)
```

This results in a very long text file with all of the information that I need, just not formatted in an ideal way.

So I am next attempting to substring this text in order to get an output that looks something like this.

Country A - Country A Score - Country B - Country B Score

It doesn't have to be exactly like this, I just basically need for each game the country and how many goals they scored and ideally it should be comparable with the other country from the same game so I can know who won or lost! I do not need any of the other information like where the game was played, etc.

So I've tried three different ways to get this:

First test: split text by dashes:

```
test <- strsplit(wcq_1934_text, "-")
df_test <- data.frame(test)
```

This gives me the information I need in a table but the rows don't match the exact scores that I need (i.e. Lithuania 0, and Sweden 2 are in separate rows)

Second test: split text by spaces:

```
test2 <- strsplit(wcq_1934_text, " ")
df_test2 <- data.frame(test2)
```

This is helpful because it gives me the scores in one row (0-2 for the first game), but the countries are unevenly spaced out across rows.

Third test: split text by "tabs"

```
test3 <- strsplit(wcq_1934_text, "    ")
df_test3 <- data.frame(test3)
```

This has a similar issue to the first test.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. This is my first ever Stack Overflow post, although I've lurked around and this website has been helpful to me for a very long time. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is pretty irregular data. Any possible solution would only work here and not on any other pages. Do you need to to be generalizeable?  You're probably better off just jumping the page into a text editor and manually cleaning it up.

Comment: You could use readLines or readr::read_lines to parse it in `read_lines("http://www.rsssf.com/tables/34q.html")` and then grep for what you're looking for.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion, I wasn't familiar with the readr package. Really helps solve some of the issues I was having with splitting that big `<pre>` block. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that provides you most of what you need, though as MrFlick commented, it is a little fragile to *this* page. I'll stay with `rvest`, though as biomiha suggested, it isn't really buying you a lot here (though it does cleanly break out the `<pre>` block).

Starting with your `wcq_1934_text`, it's a single long string, let's break it up by newlines (CRLF in this case):

```
wcq_1934_text <- strsplit(wcq_1934_text, "[\r\n]+")[[1]]
str(wcq_1934_text)
#  chr [1:51] "Hosts: Italy (not automatically qualified)" "Holders: Uruguay (did not enter)" "Group 1 [Sweden]" ...
```

I'll the `magrittr` package merely because it helps break out each step of the process using the `%>%` non-pipe; you can convert it non-`magrittr` by changing (say) `func1() %>% func2() %>% func3()` to `func3(func2(func1()))` (yuck) or intermediate assignment of return values, `ret1 <- func1(); ret2 <- func2(ret1); ...`.

```
library(magrittr)
dat <- Filter(function(a) grepl("^[0-9][0-9]", a), wcq_1934_text) %>%
  paste(., collapse = "\n") %>%
  textConnection() %>%
  read.fwf(file = ., widths = c(10, 16, 17, 4, 99), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  lapply(trimws) %>%
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The widths are fragile and unique to this page. If other reporting pages have slightly different column layouts, you'll need to use a different function, perhaps one that can automatically determine the breaks.

```
head(dat)
#        V1        V2        V3  V4       V5
# 1 11.06.33 Stockholm    Sweden 6-2  Estonia
# 2 29.06.33    Kaunas Lithuania 0-2   Sweden
# 3 11.03.34    Madrid     Spain 9-0 Portugal
# 4 18.03.34    Lisboa  Portugal 1-2    Spain
# 5 25.03.34    Milano     Italy 4-0   Greece
# 6 25.03.34     Sofia  Bulgaria 1-4  Hungary
```

From here, it's up to you which columns you want to use.

For instance, handling of the date, you might want:

```
dat$V1 <- as.POSIXct(gsub("([0-9]+)$", "19\\1", dat$V1), format = "%d.%m.%Y")
dat$V1
#  [1] "1933-06-11 PST" "1933-06-29 PST" "1934-03-11 PST" "1934-03-18 PST" "1934-03-25 PST" "1934-03-25 PST" "1934-04-25 PST" "1934-04-29 PST"
#  [9] "1933-10-15 PST" "1934-03-15 PST" "1933-09-24 PST" "1933-10-29 PST" "1934-04-29 PST" "1934-02-25 PST" "1934-04-08 PST" "1934-04-29 PST"
# [17] "1934-03-11 PST" "1934-04-15 PST" "1934-01-28 PST" "1934-02-01 PST" "1934-02-04 PST" "1934-03-04 PST" "1934-03-11 PST" "1934-03-18 PST"
# [25] "1934-05-24 PST" "1934-03-16 PST" "1934-04-06 PST"
```

The `gsub` stuff is because `as.POSIXct` assumes 2-digit years less than 69 are in the 20th century, 19th for 69-99.

It's easy enough to use either `strsplit` on the scores, but you could also do:

```
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
  separate(V4, c("score1", "score2"), sep="-") %>%
  head()
# Warning: Too few values at 1 locations: 10
#           V1        V2        V3 score1 score2       V5
# 1 1933-06-11 Stockholm    Sweden      6      2  Estonia
# 2 1933-06-29    Kaunas Lithuania      0      2   Sweden
# 3 1934-03-11    Madrid     Spain      9      0 Portugal
# 4 1934-03-18    Lisboa  Portugal      1      2    Spain
# 5 1934-03-25    Milano     Italy      4      0   Greece
# 6 1934-03-25     Sofia  Bulgaria      1      4  Hungary
```

(The warning is expected, since one game was not played so has `"n/p"` for a score. You might want to handle non-score values in `V4` before trying the split, perhaps replacing anything not numeric-dash-numeric with `NA`.)

Comment: Thank you, this is excellent. As you and MrFlick pointed out, the original data is very irregular, but since I was using it to practice and learn how to use `rvest`, this solution helped me really think through everything and further understand the problems with it.

Interestingly, it seems like this website is almost "too simple" for rvest, since all of my information gets stuck in the big fat `<pre>` block. Maybe I'll pick something else to practice on!

Comment: It depends on your purpose for practice: if you want to get better at R, then by all means try `read.lines` or other more-direct functions. If you're trying to learn scraping, I'd stick with `rvest` and benefit from (if nothing else) its auto-breakout of the `<pre>` block. If you're looking for challenges on this, the next level is to assign the `Group` text to each of these game rows, so you don't lose that bit.

Answer (score 1):

Equally specific to this particular site but may be easier to generalize:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

pg <- read_html("http://www.rsssf.com/tables/34q.html")
```

Target the `<pre>` and strip out some things that aren't part of "tables":

```
html_nodes(pg, "pre") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  stri_split_lines() %>% 
  flatten_chr() %>% 
  discard(stri_detect_regex, "^(NB|  )") -> lines
```

Now, we get the start and end lines indexes of each "group":

```
starts <- which(grepl("^Group", lines))
ends <- c(starts[-1], length(lines))
```

We iterate over those starts and ends and:

- extract the group info
- clean up the table
- discard any "empty" tables
- turn the tabular data into a data frame, doing some munging along the way

I can annotate the following more if needed:

```
map2_df(starts, ends, ~{

  grp_info <- stri_match_all_regex(lines[.x], "Group ([[:digit:]]+) \\[(.*)]")[[1]][,2:3]

  lines[(.x+1):.y] %>%
    discard(stri_detect_regex, "(^[^[:digit:]]| round)") %>% 
    discard(`==`, "") -> grp

  if (length(grp) == 0) return(NULL)

  stri_split_regex(grp, "\ \ +") %>% 
    map_df(~{
      .x[1:4] %>% 
        as.list() %>% 
        set_names(c("date", "team_a", "team_b", "score_team")) %>% 
        flatten_df() %>% 
        separate(score_team, c("score", "team_c"), sep=" ") %>% 
        mutate(group_num = grp_info[1], group_info = grp_info[2]) %>% 
        separate(date, c("d", "m", "y")) %>% 
        mutate(date = as.Date(sprintf("19%s-%s-%s", y, m, d))) %>% 
        select(-d, -m, -y)
    })

})
## # A tibble: 27 x 7
##            team_a         team_b score         team_c group_num           group_info       date
##             <chr>          <chr> <chr>          <chr>     <chr>                <chr>     <date>
##  1      Stockholm         Sweden   6-2        Estonia         1               Sweden 1933-06-11
##  2         Kaunas      Lithuania   0-2         Sweden         1               Sweden 1933-06-29
##  3         Madrid          Spain   9-0       Portugal         2                Spain 1934-03-11
##  4         Lisboa       Portugal   1-2          Spain         2                Spain 1934-03-18
##  5         Milano          Italy   4-0         Greece         3                Italy 1934-03-25
##  6          Sofia       Bulgaria   1-4        Hungary         4     Hungary, Austria 1934-03-25
##  7           Wien        Austria   6-1       Bulgaria         4     Hungary, Austria 1934-04-25
##  8       Budapest        Hungary   4-1       Bulgaria         4     Hungary, Austria 1934-04-29
##  9       Warszawa         Poland   1-2 Czechoslovakia         5       Czechoslovakia 1933-10-15
## 10          Praha Czechoslovakia   n/p         Poland         5       Czechoslovakia 1934-03-15
## 11        Beograd     Yugoslavia   2-2    Switzerland         6 Romania, Switzerland 1933-09-24
## 12           Bern    Switzerland   2-2        Romania         6 Romania, Switzerland 1933-10-29
## 13      Bucuresti        Romania   2-1     Yugoslavia         6 Romania, Switzerland 1934-04-29
## 14         Dublin        Ireland   4-4        Belgium         7 Netherlands, Belgium 1934-02-25
## 15      Amsterdam    Netherlands   5-2        Ireland         7 Netherlands, Belgium 1934-04-08
## 16      Antwerpen        Belgium   2-4    Netherlands         7 Netherlands, Belgium 1934-04-29
## 17     Luxembourg     Luxembourg   1-9        Germany         8      Germany, France 1934-03-11
## 18     Luxembourg     Luxembourg   1-6         France         8      Germany, France 1934-04-15
## 19 Port-au-Prince          Haiti   1-3           Cuba        11                  USA 1934-01-28
## 20 Port-au-Prince          Haiti   1-1           Cuba        11                  USA 1934-02-01
## 21 Port-au-Prince          Haiti   0-6           Cuba        11                  USA 1934-02-04
## 22  Cd. de Mexico         Mexico   3-2           Cuba        11                  USA 1934-03-04
## 23  Cd. de Mexico         Mexico   5-0           Cuba        11                  USA 1934-03-11
## 24  Cd. de Mexico         Mexico   4-1           Cuba        11                  USA 1934-03-18
## 25           Roma            USA   4-2         Mexico        11                  USA 1934-05-24
## 26          Cairo          Egypt   7-1      Palestina        12                Egypt 1934-03-16
## 27       Tel Aviv      Palestina   1-4          Egypt        12                Egypt 1934-04-06
```

Comment: Nice. I started going down the road of `starts`/`ends` but ran out of time, nice you kept `group_info` in there. I had thought about the regexp for splitting the table but thought it could run into problems ...